# Unable to install qt-sdk unmet dependencies

Tags: installation, apt, qt

I tried to install qt-sdk under ubuntu 12.10 how can I fix this issue?

install log:

```
apt-get install qt-sdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qt-sdk : Depends: qt4-designer but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: qt4-dev-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

First do

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator 
sudo apt-get install qt4-designer
sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools
```

then

`sudo apt-get install qt-sdk`

Comment: I didn't same steps as soon as I face this issue... it didn't fix it!

Comment: qtcreator already installed

Comment: Have you tried installing qt designer and dev tools?

Comment: when I tried to: `sudo apt-get install qt4-designer` I got this error message.

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:`

Comment: `qt4-designer : Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu4~quantal1~test4 is to be installed`

Comment: `Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu4~quantal1~test4 is to be installed
                Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu4~quantal1~test4 is to be installed`

Comment: `Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu4~quantal1~test4 is to be installed
                Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu4~quantal1~test4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Looks like a kernel mismatch here. Can you please show me the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list` is empty!!!